# Determinant of a nxn matrix with function recursion in c programming

Tags: c, recursion, matrix

I want to correct this code to calculate determinant of a nxn matrix. The code below is what I have done so far. but it's giving the right answer up to 3x3 matrices and greater than that it is giving wrong value. I've also checked the part separately where minor matrices are formed from the main matrix and it is working perfectly. Still I don't know why it is returning wrong value for 4x4 and greater matrices?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

int dete(int, int (*)[]);

int main()
{
   int a[3][3]=
   {
        1,4,3,
        2,1,5,
        3,2,1
   };

   int b[4][4]=
   {
        5,3,-2,-6,
        1,2,7,4,
        -10,3,5,-3,
        -4,2,6,1
   };

    int ans1,ans2;
    ans1=dete(3,a);//ans1 = 46 and this is correct
    ans2=dete(4,b);//ans2 = 174 but it is giving 5169 which is wrong
    printf("%d, %d", ans1, ans2);
    getch();
}

int dete(int row, int arr[][row])
{
     int col_main_mark,col_main,row_main,col_minor,cof,x,y;
     int minor[row-1][row-1];
     static int det=0;

     if(row==2)//condition to stop recursion
     {
          det = arr[0][0] * arr[1][1] - arr[0][1] * arr[1][0];
          return det;
     }

     for(col_main_mark=0; col_main_mark<row; col_main_mark++)//for specific col value of main matrix (arr[row][row])
     {
          cof=arr[0][col_main_mark];

          //following two loop will make the minor matrix (minor[row-1][row-1]) from the main marix
          for(row_main=0; row_main<row; row_main++)
          {
               for(col_main=0,col_minor=0; col_main<row; col_main++)
               {
                    if(col_main==col_main_mark)
                    continue;

                    minor[row_main][col_minor]=arr[row_main+1][col_main]; col_minor++;
               }
          }

          det = det + cof * pow(-1,col_main_mark) * dete(row-1, minor);  
     }
     return det;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I think that you need to remove the `static` from `static int det=0;`

Comment: Why did you put `static` before `int det=0;` in the first place? What was your thought process there? Maybe you have a misunderstanding of what it does.

Comment: This is a very good example of [mre]. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to remove `static`. The variable `det` will only be zero the first time the function is run. The next time it will have have the same value as it had in the end of the last call.

You can try with a two or more 3x3 matrices in a row. Only the first call to `dete` will yield the correct result.

Comment: I've tried removing the static keyword, also I've tried with 2 or more 3x3 matrices in a row and it works fine. I've also made the det global and it also works only for 3x3 matrices. but none of that works for 4x4 or greater dimension matrices. What to do now?

Comment: @AbhirupBakshi But why on earth cannot you just let it be a local variable? It makes NO sense at all to have it as either static or global.

Comment: Yea I made it a auto variable and it worked. Thanks